# Woocommerce: How to trigger action when datepicker is selected

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, woocommerce, datepicker

i have added 2 datepicker fields to woocommerce checkout page.
Now i want to execute a script which calculates the number of days between both datepicker field values.

But im struggeling with the basics to call the calculation script after both datepickers have been selected and the variables "order_pickup_date" and "order_pickup_EndDate" do have values.

**Here is the code for the 2 datepicker fields:**

```
// Call datepicker functionality in custom text field

add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field', 10, 1);
function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
    $mydateoptions = array('' => __('Select PickupDate', 'woocommerce' ));

    echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field">
    <h3>'.__('Date pre-order').'</h3>';

    echo '
    <script>
        jQuery(function($){
            $("#datepicker").datepicker( {
            minDate:1,
            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
       var show = true;       
       if(date.getDay()==1||date.getDay()==1 ) show=false
       return [show];
       }       
       } )});
    </script>';

    echo '
     <script>
        jQuery(function($){
            $("#datepickerEnd").datepicker( {
            minDate:($("#order_pickup_date")+3),
            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
       var show = true;
       if(date.getDay()==1) show=false
       return [show];

       }} )});
    </script>';

   woocommerce_form_field( 'order_pickup_date', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('form-row-first my-datepicker'),
        'id'            => 'datepicker',
        'required'      => true,
        'label'         => __('Start pre-order'),
        'placeholder'       => __('Select Date'),
        'options'     =>   $mydateoptions
        ),$checkout->get_value( 'order_pickup_date' ));

    woocommerce_form_field( 'order_pickup_EndDate', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('form-row-first my-datepicker'),
        'id'            => 'datepickerEnd',
        'required'      => true,
        'label'         => __('Ende pre-order'),
        'placeholder'       => __('Select Date'),
        'options'     =>   $mydateoptions
        ),$checkout->get_value( 'order_pickup_EndDate' ));

    echo '</div>';
}
```

Now i want to call the below script after both datepickers have values:

```
function wnd_checkout_code( ) {
 $from= $_POST['order_pickup_date'];
    $to=$_POST['order_pickup_EndDate'];
    $start='Sunday';
    $end='Monday';
    $day_num=['Monday'=>1,'Tuesday'=>2,'Wednesday'=>3,'Thursday'=>4,'Friday'=>5,'Saturday'=>6,'Sunday'=>7];
    $start_num=$day_num[$start];
    $end_num=$day_num[$end];


    $period=new DatePeriod(date_create($from),date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 days'),date_create($to));
    $nRange=0;

    if($start_num===$end_num){
        $valid_range=array_values($day_num);//keep the number of each day of the week
    }
    elseif($start_num>$end_num){
        $valid_range=array_values($day_num);//keep the number of each day of the week
        while($valid_range[0]!==$start_num){//rotate the values to keep the start day first
            $pop=array_shift($valid_range);
            array_push($valid_range,$pop);

        }
        $valid_range=array_slice($valid_range,array_search($start_num,$valid_range),$start_num-$end_num);//keep only the days in the chosen range
    }else{
        $valid_range=array_values($day_num);//keep the number of each day of the week
        $valid_range=array_slice($valid_range,array_search($start_num,$valid_range),$end_num-$start_num); //keep only the days in the chosen range
    }
    $valid_range=array_flip($valid_range);//flip the array to make the search more fast
    foreach($period as $date){
        if(isset($valid_range[(int)$date->format('N')])){
            $nRange++;
        }
    }

    print_r($nRange+1);//output the number  of valid days 
}
```

Can you help me out as i am a beginner working on this.